# Removing chapter number

Tags: sectioning

How can I remove chapter number. I want it just for chapter of "Acronyms". Please look this code:

```
\chapter{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}

\acro{ACK}{\textit{Acknowledgment command}}
\acro{AIS}{\textit{Automatic Identification Systems}}
...
\end{acronym}
```

When I used `\chapter*{Acronyms}` I removed number but have in the header name, the name of previous chapter.

Comment: If you use a KOMA class you could use `\addchap{Acronyms}`. With one of the standard classes `\chapter*{Acronyms}\markboth{Acronyms}{Acronyms}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}` or a slight variation thereof might work.

Comment: Please consider choosing your tags with slightly more diligence. This question has nothing to do with `biblatex` (a package to produce bibliographies) or LaTeX3 (the `expl3` language).

Comment: using `\chapter*` seems like the right approach, but you have to set the running heads explicitly.  for that, add `\markboth{Acronyms}{Acronyms}` right after the `\chapter*` line.